# 2 calculators at the same time using javascript class template

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object

I am trying to run 2 calculators at the same time. The code I have so far works only on the 1st calculator, however the 2nd one does not work.

here is a link to the project https://codepen.io/Zerka1982/pen/OJwVygy?editors=1010

looking forward to your support. thanks!

I tried to change the data name in the attribute inside HTML for the 2nd calculator

```
class MyCalculator {
    constructor(previousValueTextElement, currentValueTextElement) {
        this.previousValueTextElement = previousValueTextElement
        this.currentValueTextElement = currentValueTextElement
        this.clearScreen()
    }
    clearScreen() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }
    deleteLastNumber() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
    }
    appendNumber(number) {
        // Add 0 at the beginning if numbers start with ('.')
        if(number.startsWith('.')) this.currentOperand = '0' + this.currentOperand.toString()
        // Verify if the dot is clicked or the number already contains the dot [no action]
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
    }
    chooseOperator(operation) {
        if(this.currentOperand === '' || this.currentOperand === undefined) return
        if(this.previousOperand !== '') {
            this.calculate()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
    }
    // Method to handle the arithmetic calculation
    calculate() {
        let result
        const previousValue = parseFloat(this.previousOperand) 
        const currentValue = parseFloat(this.currentOperand) 
        if(isNaN(previousValue) || isNaN(currentValue)) return
        // Switch statement to handle different operations
        switch(this.operation) {
            case '+':
                result =  previousValue + currentValue
            break
            case '*':
                result =  previousValue * currentValue
            break
            case '-':
                result =  previousValue - currentValue
            break
            case '/':
                result =  previousValue / currentValue
            break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = result
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
    }
    getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
          integerDisplay = ''
        } else {
          integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
        }
        if (decimalDigits != null) {
          return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
        } else {
          return integerDisplay
        }
      }
    // Method to update the output result
    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentValueTextElement.innerText = 
        this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
        if (this.operation != null) {
            this.previousValueTextElement.innerText =
                `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
        } else {
            this.previousValueTextElement.innerText = ''
        }
    }
}

// Get all variables
const numberBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const clearScreenBtn = document.querySelector('[data-clear-all]')
const previousValueTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-value]')
const currentValueTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-actual-value]')

const previousValueTextElement1 = document.querySelector('[data-previous-value1]')
const currentValueTextElement1 = document.querySelector('[data-actual-value1]')

const calculator = new MyCalculator(previousValueTextElement, currentValueTextElement)
const calculator1 = new MyCalculator(previousValueTextElement1, currentValueTextElement1)


// The forEach() method executes a function once for each [button number]
numberBtns.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

// The forEach() method executes a function once for each operation [+,-,*,/]
operationBtns.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.chooseOperator(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

// method is to register an event listener for equal button
equalButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.calculate()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

// Clear the screen [the output result]
clearScreenBtn.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.clearScreen()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
// Delete last added number 
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.deleteLastNumber()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

// Allow user to use the keyboard
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(
        // Allow user to use the keyboard numbers [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        e.key === '0' || e.key === '1' || e.key === '2' || 
        e.key === '3' || e.key === '4' || e.key === '5' || 
        e.key === '6' || e.key === '7' || e.key === '8' || 
        e.key === '9' || e.key === '.'
    ) {
        calculator.appendNumber(e.key)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    } else if (
        // Allow user to use the keyboard operators [+,*,-,/] 
        e.key === '*' || e.key === '+' || e.key === '-' || e.key === '/'
    ) {
        calculator.chooseOperator(e.key)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    } else if ( e.key === 'Enter') {
        // Allow user to use the keyboard ['Enter'] to get result
        calculator.calculate()
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    } else if ( e.key === 'c' || e.key === 'C' || e.key === 'delete') {
        // Allow user to use the keyboard ['c','C', 'delete'] to clear screen
        calculator.clearScreen()
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    } else if ( e.key === 'd' || e.key === 'D' || e.key === 'Backspace') {
        // Allow user to use the keyboard  ['d','D'] to delete last number
        calculator.deleteLastNumber()
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    } else {
        // Do not allow user to use other keys than the predefined ones
        alert(' This key is not allowed ')
    }
})

// Disable right-click
//document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => e.preventDefault());

/*function ctrlShiftKey(e, keyCode) {
  return e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === keyCode.charCodeAt(0);
}*/

// Disable F12, Ctrl + Shift + I, Ctrl + Shift + J, Ctrl + U
/*
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (
    event.keyCode === 123 ||
    ctrlShiftKey(e, 'I') ||
    ctrlShiftKey(e, 'J') ||
    ctrlShiftKey(e, 'C') ||
    (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 'U'.charCodeAt(0))
  )
    return false;
};*/
```

Comment: you have to make sure your calculator class is fully encapsulated. Move all global functions, variables and event listeners inside the class so that they create one independent instance. It's not a quick fix sadly. edit: `// Get all variables` everything below this should be inside the calculator class.

Comment: Is it possible that you share with me your thought how I suppose to move everything below // Get all variables inside the class ?

Comment: Do it step by step. First, think about how you want to contain all these global variables. Maybe you have a wrapper element for your calculator that you use to init it. Then you can find all `numberBns` by using `wrapperElement.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')` ... and then the same for all other buttons. Then think about how to add event listeners to these contained buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (not the best one I guess) using 2 calculators, however I am looking for more dynamic approach. Please, fell free to suggest a solution if you have one.

I added id(s) to each HTML calculator, then on the JS part, I used e.target.parentNode.id to check which Calculator I am typing in, then simply through if statements, I could have the calculation up running

See bellow solution
https://codepen.io/Zerka1982/pen/OJwVygy?editors=1010

If you have a dynamic solution to as many calculators as possible, please feel free to leave a comment or a code example. Thanks!

```html
numberBtns.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let parentNodeID = e.target.parentNode.id
    if( parentNodeID === 'calculatorID1') {
      calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
      calculator.updateDisplay()
    } else {
      calculator1.appendNumber(button.innerText)
      calculator1.updateDisplay()
    }
  })
})
```